# XML data file problem

Tags: xml

I have a element that is boolean in XML schema. Iam making a .XML file in which I am writing the values for the elements.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [XML Schema specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean), the canonical representation for a boolean datatype is either `true` or `false`:

> *3.2.2.1 Lexical representation*
>   An instance of a datatype that is
>   defined as boolean can have the
>   following legal literals {true, false,
>   1, 0}.
>
> *3.2.2.2 Canonical representation*
>   The canonical representation for
>   boolean is the set of literals {true,
>   false}.

In your application, you want to convert the literals `true` and `false` into either a blank or an "X". This is something that should be handled by your XML parser, not by the schema.

Comment: I am writing .xml file. So, I need to know how to put a blank and X in that file. The schema is already done by me. I am making data file now.